# why won't my text print to my JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, variables, jtextarea

I am calling a method that returns a string (edited text from a webpage) and I want to print that string onto my JTextArea. I know that string I am sending to my JTextArea is correct because it will print correctly to the command line, but will not print to the JTextArea. It must be something I am doing wrong in my adding it to the TextArea. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BrowserPanel extends JPanel {

private JTextField textField;
private String urlText;
private JTextArea textArea;
private BrowserPageReader myModel;
private String pageContent;
private BrowserFrame myFrame;
private String pageTitle;
private String pageBody;



public BrowserPanel(JTextField myTextField, BrowserPageReader model,
        BrowserFrame frame)
{
    myFrame = frame;
    myModel = model;
    textField = myTextField;
    textField.addActionListener(new InputHandler());

    /*JScrollPane areaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    areaScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    areaScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,250));*/
    textArea = new JTextArea(20,40);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    add(scroll);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

}
private class InputHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
         urlText = textField.getText();  
         //textArea.append(urlText);

         myModel.setURL(urlText);
         pageTitle = myModel.getTitle();
         myFrame.setTitle(pageTitle);
        pageBody = myModel.getBody();
        textArea.setText(pageBody); 
         System.out.println(pageBody); //This prints out exactly what Im wanting
                                       //  Its just a test             
         textArea.repaint();
    }
}
}
```

I'm guessing I maybe need to add something to my paintComponent since my TextArea is in a scrollPane that is attached to my Panel. I just really cant figure out what is wrong. If i put `textArea.setText("blah");` it does what it should. The variable I am sending in is a very large string, its an entire webpage. Could that be the problem? With the code as is the textArea remains blank and what i'm wanting it to show prints correctly to the command line. HELP!

*Edit* here is the rest of my code

```
  import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class BrowserFrame extends JFrame{

public BrowserFrame()
{
    BrowserPageReader myModel = new BrowserPageReader();
    setTitle("My Browser");
    Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension screenSize =kit.getScreenSize();
    setSize(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height-500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
    BrowserPanel myPanel = new BrowserPanel(textField,myModel,this);
    contentPane.add(myPanel);
    contentPane.add(textField,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    setVisible(true);

}
}





 import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class BrowserPageReader {

private URL myURL;
//private String webURL;
private String totalWebContent;
private String htmlString;
private String contentToPrint = " ";
private String urlPath;
private String urlHost;
private String pageTitle;
private String pageBody;
private String formattedBody;

public void setURL (String webURL)
{
   try{
        myURL = new URL(webURL);
        urlPath = myURL.getPath();
        urlHost = myURL.getHost();

    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"URL is incorrectly formatted");
    }
}

public void retrieveContent()
{
    try{
        Socket socket = new Socket(urlHost,80);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new
                BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out.print("GET " + urlPath + " HTTP/1.1\n");
        out.print("Host: "+ urlHost + "\n");
        out.print("\n");
        out.flush();
        while((totalWebContent = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //System.out.println(totalWebContent);
            htmlString = htmlString + totalWebContent;
            //System.out.println(contentToPrint);
        }
        //System.out.println("htmlString\n" + htmlString);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getTitle()
{
       retrieveContent();
      //System.out.println(htmlString);
      pageTitle = htmlString.substring(htmlString.indexOf("<title>")+ 7,
              htmlString.indexOf("</title>")); 
      return pageTitle;
}

public String getBody()
{
    String toDelete;
    String edited;
    retrieveContent();

    pageBody = htmlString.substring(htmlString.indexOf("<body")+5,
            htmlString.indexOf("</body>"));
    toDelete = pageBody.substring(0,pageBody.indexOf('<'));
    edited = pageBody.replace(toDelete,"");
    pageBody = edited
    formattedBody = pageBody.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
    //System.out.println(formattedBody);
    return formattedBody;

}
```

Comment: so you're saying if you change textArea.setText(pageBody);  to textArea.setText("blah"); blah shows up in the textArea?

Comment: Yep, thats exactly what happens

Comment: I think perhaps it might have something to do with `pagebody` being really big, but I dont know

Comment: there's a lot of quotes in the the page, are you escaping them out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your posted code is not an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org), a small self-contained program that we can compile, run, and test, I don't think that we answer this without guessing. And so my guess: the JTextArea that you're adding text to is not the same one as is being displayed in a JFrame.

To be able to answer this with confidence though, we need that [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org), especially the code showing where you create the class above and where you add it to the JFrame that is displayed.

For instance, if I create a small [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) with mock BrowserFrame JFrame and BrowserPageReader model classes, everything seems to work fine:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BrowserPanel extends JPanel {

   private JTextField textField;
   private String urlText;
   private JTextArea textArea;
   private BrowserPageReader myModel;
   private String pageContent;
   private BrowserFrame myFrame;
   private String pageTitle;
   private String pageBody;

   public BrowserPanel(JTextField myTextField, BrowserPageReader model,
         BrowserFrame frame) {
      myFrame = frame;
      myModel = model;
      textField = myTextField;
      textField.addActionListener(new InputHandler());

      /*
       * JScrollPane areaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
       * areaScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
       * JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
       * 
       * areaScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,250));
       */
      textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
      textArea.setEditable(false);
      textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      textArea.setLineWrap(true);
      JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);

      add(scroll);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

   }

   private class InputHandler implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         urlText = textField.getText();
         // textArea.append(urlText);

         myModel.setURL(urlText);
         pageTitle = myModel.getTitle();
         myFrame.setTitle(pageTitle);
         pageBody = myModel.getBody();
         textArea.setText(pageBody);
         System.out.println(pageBody); // This prints out exactly what Im
                                       // wanting
                                       // Its just a test
         textArea.repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      BrowserFrame frame = new BrowserFrame();
      JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
      BrowserPageReader myModel = new BrowserPageReader();
      BrowserPanel mainPanel = new BrowserPanel(textField, myModel, frame);

      frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class BrowserFrame extends JFrame {

}

class BrowserPageReader {

   public void setURL(String urlText) {
      // does nothing for now. for testing purposes.
   }

   public String getBody() {
      return "body"; // for testing purposes
   }

   public String getTitle() {
      return "title"; // for testing purposes
   }

}
```

Since my code "works" it proves that the error is not in the code you've posted above.

Your job is to post similar code that *doesn't* work fine, that instead demonstrates your problem. I'm guessing that if you put in the effort to create such a program, you'll isolate the error, you'll see where you've likely got two BrowserPanels, one displayed and one that is not displayed but is getting its text changed in the handler, and you'll be able to solve your error without our direct help.

---

**Edit**
SwingWorker e.g.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;

public class BrowserPanel extends JPanel {

   private JTextField textField;
   private String urlText;
   private JTextArea textArea;
   private BrowserPageReader myModel;
   private String pageContent;
   private BrowserFrame myFrame;
   private String pageTitle;
   private String pageBody;

   public BrowserPanel(JTextField myTextField, BrowserPageReader model,
         BrowserFrame frame) {
      myFrame = frame;
      myModel = model;
      textField = myTextField;
      textField.addActionListener(new InputHandler());

      /*
       * JScrollPane areaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
       * areaScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
       * JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
       * 
       * areaScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,250));
       */
      textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
      textArea.setEditable(false);
      textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      textArea.setLineWrap(true);
      JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);

      add(scroll);
   }

   private class InputHandler implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         urlText = textField.getText();
         // textArea.append(urlText);
         System.out.println(urlText);

         myModel.setURL(urlText);

         myModel.getContent(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
               if (SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE == evt.getNewValue()) {
                  pageTitle = myModel.getTitle();
                  myFrame.setTitle(pageTitle);
                  pageBody = myModel.getBody();
                  textArea.setText(pageBody);
                  System.out.println(pageBody);
               }
            }
         });
         // textArea.repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      BrowserFrame frame = new BrowserFrame();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class BrowserFrame extends JFrame {

   public BrowserFrame() {
      BrowserPageReader myModel = new BrowserPageReader();
      setTitle("My Browser");
      Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();
      setSize(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height - 500);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Container contentPane = getContentPane();
      JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
      BrowserPanel myPanel = new BrowserPanel(textField, myModel, this);
      contentPane.add(myPanel);
      contentPane.add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      setVisible(true);

   }
}

class BrowserPageReader {

   private URL myURL;
   // private String webURL;
   private String totalWebContent;
   private String htmlString;
   private String contentToPrint = " ";
   private String urlPath;
   private String urlHost;
   private String pageTitle;
   private String pageBody;
   private String formattedBody;

   public void setURL(String webURL) {
      try {
         myURL = new URL(webURL);
         urlPath = myURL.getPath();
         urlHost = myURL.getHost();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "URL is incorrectly formatted");
      }
   }

   public void getContent(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      RetrieveWorker worker = new RetrieveWorker();
      worker.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
      worker.execute();
   }

   private void retrieveContent() {
      try {
         Socket socket = new Socket(urlHost, 80);
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
               socket.getInputStream()));
         out.print("GET " + urlPath + " HTTP/1.1\n");
         out.print("Host: " + urlHost + "\n");
         out.print("\n");
         out.flush();
         while ((totalWebContent = in.readLine()) != null) {
            // System.out.println(totalWebContent);
            htmlString = htmlString + totalWebContent;
            // System.out.println(contentToPrint);
         }
         // System.out.println("htmlString\n" + htmlString);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public String getTitle() {
      // !! retrieveContent();
      System.out.println(htmlString);
      pageTitle = htmlString.substring(htmlString.indexOf("<title>") + 7,
            htmlString.indexOf("</title>"));
      return pageTitle;
   }

   public String getBody() {
      String toDelete;
      String edited;
      // !! retrieveContent();

      pageBody = htmlString.substring(htmlString.indexOf("<body") + 5,
            htmlString.indexOf("</body>"));
      toDelete = pageBody.substring(0, pageBody.indexOf('<'));
      edited = pageBody.replace(toDelete, "");
      pageBody = edited;
      formattedBody = pageBody.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
      // System.out.println(formattedBody);
      return formattedBody;

   }

   private class RetrieveWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
         retrieveContent();
         return null;
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: well i added my textArea to my Panel and then my panel to my frame.

Comment: I am not sure how to make/post a program that you can run or else I would for you

Comment: And the code I posted above works, aka the `System.out.println` stuff in my handler, my panel is obviously working out.

Comment: I mean I can get my TextArea to display text, I just want get it to display the text I want. if I put `textArea.append("blah!")`  just above where I am putting `textarea.append(pageBody)' it will put "blahh" on the Text area, but not the stuff stored in `pagebody`

Comment: @GabrielleLee: your newly posted code does not observe Swing threading rules which could possibly mess things up. You really should do most all of the work in the `retrieveContent(...)` in a background thread such as that which is available with a SwingWorker.

Comment: @GabrielleLee: how is your program supposed to work? What text is supposed to go into the JTextArea?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels he's converting a webpage to a string. said string is printing to the console fine, but not to the text area. when he types in a literal string rather than the string reference, it displays properly

Comment: @JeffHawthorne: I know, but any old web URL won't work, at least not for me. I'm asking him to post the URL he is testing his code on.

Comment: Its suposed to be a mock web browser. I have a textfield that a user enters a webpage. I send that webpage over to my BrowserPageReader which accesses the website and pulls only certain information from the HTML. The string containing the HMTL from the webpage that I want to display is sent back to my Inputhandler, in the string pageBody

Comment: @GabrielleLee: right, but what web page url are you reading? When I tested it with this one: [Pitt Community College IS](http://www.pittcc.edu/academics/programs/business-division/information-systems/) it seemed to work.

Comment: @JeffHawthorne Ill try it on that webpage real quick

Comment: @JeffHawthorne Oh wow youre right. It did work for that webpage. I have no idea why that random wiki page isn't working then

Comment: @GabrielleLee: the web page was posted by me. Again your code is running afoul of Swing's threading rules. This can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: that was @HovercraftFullOfEels not me. my guess would be that there is a bad character in the wiki page that is escaping out of your string and messing it up

Comment: @JeffHawthorne it looks like it will work for some pages, but not others. It wouldn't work for http://go.okstate.edu/ either

Comment: Also, for something like this, I'd use a web parser such as JSoup.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it will work for that page, but won't for like http://go.okstate.edu/

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not allowed to. I have to do that stuff myself as part of the assignment

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I take it back, it eventually worked for http://go.okstate.edu/ it just took forever. So i guess its working that one webpage was just dumb. Thanks guys!

Comment: @GabrielleLee: you're welcome. I posted a quick and dirty SwingWorker example, but you should really read the tutorial on this.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your input handler is getting called multiple times.  The text could be set to the body text, then print, then be set back to empty for some reason.  Test this in your system.out.println statment by adding

```
System.out.println("outputStart: " + pagebody + " :END");
```

Then you'll be able to tell how many times your input handler ran.

Comment: Yes, because the way you have it written now, you won't be able to tell if it ran multiple times.  If pagebody is blank, a blank line will be printed which wouldn't be very easy to see.

Comment: Well I put that it but it didn't really tell me anything useful. Plus my code the way it was, it only `System.out.println` 'd it once

Comment: It only got called once, aka it only printed once

Comment: Id suggest debugging then.